# Is it possible to nest GROUP BY statements inside of each other?

Tags: mysql

I have the following table

```
video_id    ip_address
1           192.168.1.1
1           192.168.1.1
1           192.168.1.2
2           192.168.1.2
2           192.168.1.2
2           192.168.1.2
```

Running the following query returns the amount of unique requests per video per ip address.

```
SELECT video_id, COUNT(*) as num_unique_requests FROM 
    (SELECT video_id, ip_address FROM videos
    GROUP BY video_id, ip_address) t
GROUP BY video_id
ORDER BY num_unique_requests DESC

video_id    num_unique_requests
1           2
2           1
```

Is there any way I can nest the innermost `GROUP BY` statement with another `GROUP BY` statement so I can avoid creating the outermost statement to `GROUP BY` `video_id?`

Is there any other way to write this query more efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use **COUNT(DISTINCT FILEDNAME)**

```
SELECT video_id, COUNT( DISTINCT ip_address) as num_unique_requests FROM 
videos
GROUP BY video_id
ORDER BY num_unique_requests DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case, `DISTINCT` in the inner query is apt, in place of `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT video_id, COUNT(*) as num_unique_requests 
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT video_id, ip_address FROM videos) t
GROUP BY video_id
ORDER BY num_unique_requests DESC
```